# Evaluating logpdf of vector of observations where each observation has different mean parameter

Tags: statistics, julia, bayesian

New to Julia and just trying to implement a basic Bayesian model. I would like to evaluate the log-likelihood of each data point, where each data point has a different mean parameter depending on their corresponding covariate, without having to implement a for loop over all data points.

```
using Distributions 

y = -50:1:49
a = 1
b = 1
N = 100
x = rand(Normal(0, 1), N)
mu = a .+ b.*x
sigma = 5
# Can we evaluate the logpdf of every point in one call to logpdf without doing a for loop
loglikelihood = logpdf(Normal(mu, sigma), y)

MethodError: no method matching Normal(::Vector{Float64}, ::Int64)
```

**Edit:** I would like to clarify that the `mu` specified above is a vector of the same dimensions as `y`, and that instead evaluating `logpdf` of each observation using the function `Normal(::Real, ::Real)` in an iterative procedure, I would like to something that handles something to the effect of
`logpdf(Normal(::Array, ::Real), ::Array)`. The code I provide in the following chunk does what I want by taking the sum of the log-likelihood across observations, but I would prefer to not have to transform to a multivariate distribution.

```
using LinearAlgebra

logpdf(MvNormal(mu, diagm(repeat([sigma], outer=N))), y)
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't actually run, as there are undefined variables (`a`, `b`, `y`). But in general what you're asking works out of the box:

```
julia> using Distributions

julia> μ = 2.0; σ = 3.0;

julia> logpdf(Normal(μ, σ), 0:0.5:4)
9-element Vector{Float64}:
 -2.2397730440950046
 -2.1425508218727822
 -2.073106377428338
 -2.0314397107616715
 -2.0175508218727827
 -2.0314397107616715
 -2.073106377428338
 -2.1425508218727822
 -2.2397730440950046
```

Here I'm getting the log pdf at values 0, 0.5, 1, ..., 3.5, 4. This works because there's a method for `logpdf` which takes an `AbstractArray` as second argument:

```
julia> @which logpdf(Normal(μ, σ), 0:0.5:4)
logpdf(d::UnivariateDistribution{S} where S<:ValueSupport, X::AbstractArray) in Distributions at deprecated.jl:70

julia> @which logpdf(Normal(μ, σ), 0.5)
logpdf(d::Normal, x::Real) in Distributions at ...\Distributions\bawf4\src\univariate\continuous\normal.jl:105
```

As you see there though, that method signature is actually deprecated. Let's start Julia with `depwarn=yes` to see the deprecation notice:

```
$> julia --depwarn=yes

julia> using Distributions

julia> logpdf(Normal(), 1:10)
┌ Warning: `logpdf(d::UnivariateDistribution, X::AbstractArray)` is deprecated, use `logpdf.(d, X)` instead.
│   caller = top-level scope at REPL[4]:1
└ @ Core REPL[4]:1
```

What this tells you is that actually you don't need a method signature which accepts an array, as Julia's built-in broadcasting syntax - appending a dot to a function call - gives you this for free. Returning to the first example:

```
julia> logpdf.(Normal(μ, σ), 0:0.5:4)
9-element Vector{Float64}:
 -2.2397730440950046
 -2.1425508218727822
 -2.073106377428338
 -2.0314397107616715
 -2.0175508218727827
 -2.0314397107616715
 -2.073106377428338
 -2.1425508218727822
 -2.2397730440950046
```

Here, I'm actually calling the `logpdf(d::Normal, x::Real)` method, but the `.` after `logpdf` applies the function elementwise to the range `0:0.5:4`.

The broadcast syntax also extends to constructors, so you can use it to construct multiple normal distributions with different mean:

```
julia> μ = rand(3)
3-element Vector{Float64}:
 0.5341692431981215
 0.5696647074299088
 0.3021675356902611

julia> Normal.(μ, 5)
3-element Vector{Normal{Float64}}:
 Normal{Float64}(μ=0.5341692431981215, σ=5.0)
 Normal{Float64}(μ=0.5696647074299088, σ=5.0)
 Normal{Float64}(μ=0.3021675356902611, σ=5.0)
```

that's what the error above is telling you - the `Normal` constructor does not accept a vector as first element, but a single value. If you want to apply it to multiple values, just broadcast!

Comment: Hi Nils, I have edited the question such that it is now a working example. The example you provided defined `mu` as a scalar but I would like to define `mu` to be a vector of the same dimension as the data observations.

Comment: Did you see the end of my answer? Broadcasting also works for the `Normal` constructor if `mu` is a vector.

Comment: Oops I missed it, awesome thanks for your help! I love julia